# Copy image class to outer container

Tags: jquery, class, copy

I have several images and they all have several classes:

```
<span class="featured">
  <img src="my_src.jpg" class="alignright gallery single-image" />
</span>
```

The `featured` span has a `display: inline-block` attribute, which messes up the align class added on the image. These images are dynamic, so I can't control which align property is used. What I'd like to do is use jQuery copy the align property of the image (if it's set) and add it to the container:

```
<span class="featured alignright">
  <img src="my_src.jpg" class="alignright gallery single-image" />
</span>
```

That way I can keep my `display: inline-block` on the `featured` container and the images will still float on the side they are designated.

The classes I'm using are `alignleft` (`float: left`)and `alighright` (`float: right`).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Why not just amend the CSS so that you don't need to hack around some JS to fix the UI?

Comment: I'm using a color overlay when someone hovers over the image that uses the `display: inline-block` property, so that has to stay or the overlay stops working.

Comment: That still doesn't sound like it excludes changing your CSS rules to fix the problem.

Comment: The main reason for this change was because users have the ability to make an image right aligned or left aligned through a WYSIWYG interface. I have no idea when they make this change, so if I can add that property to my outer div then that'll fix the issue because those properties are just float right and float left. I did not make any additional css modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the jquery parent function on the  tag or single-image class.

For example:

- $( ".single-image" ).parent().addClass( "alignright");
- $( ".alignright" ).parent().addClass( "alignright");
- $( ".alignleft" ).parent().addClass( "alignleft");

The .parent() will exactly jump to the img parent tag which is span so this should work. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: On the featured class you can also have some css property that overrides its display property. Forexample .featured { display: inline-block !important; }